# search for a header and put that header in a list

Tags: c#, linq, text-files

I have a textfile with blogposts, each blogpost is divided in a header and content shown below

```
    #Header
    A post
    #Content
    My content goes here...
    #Header
    Another post
    #Content
    My content goes here...
```

Now I want to grab all the headers, the text that comes after #Header and before #Content and put that in a `List<>`. How can I do that?

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
var headers = new List<string>();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Path))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                headers.AddRange(line)
                    .SkipWhile(l => l != "#Header")
                    .Skip(1)
                    .TakeWhile(l => !l.StartsWith("#"))
                    .ToList();
            }
        }
```

Linq is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but how about something like this (assuming the file isn't *that* long):

```
var headers = reader.ReadToEnd()
    .Split(new[]{"#Header"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x => x.Split(new[]{"#Content"})[0].Trim())
    .ToList();
```

Or, reading line-by-line, if the file is long:

```
List<string> headers = new List<string>();

string line;
bool inHeader = false;
StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder();

while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if(!inHeader)
    {
        if (line == "#Header") inHeader = true;
    }
    else if (line == "#Content")
    {
        headers.Add(header.ToString());
        header.Clear();
        inHeader = false;
    }            
    else
    {
        header.AppendLine(line);
    }
}

if(inHeader) headers.Add(header.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your file can be very long:

```
bool header = false;
while(line = reader.readLine())
{
    if(header) headers.add(line);
    if(String.Compare(line,"#Header", false) == 0)
    {
        header = true;
    }
    else if(String.Compare(line,"#Content", false) == 0)
    {
        header = false;
    }
}
```

Of course this assumes that your headers are always exactly one line long (otherwise one header can result in multiple entries in your headers variable).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` with `LINQ`

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText("yourTextFile.txt");

List<string> header=Regex.Matches(contents,@"#Header\s*(.*?)\s*#",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline)
.Cast<Match>()
.Select(x=>x.Groups[1].Value).ToList<string>();
```